# 9patch image error only with android studio not with Eclipse

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-imageview, android-drawable

I couldn't observe this bug with eclipse

> /Users/Shravan/Documents/Git/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/password.9.png
>   **Error:Ticks in transparent frame must be black or red. - Found at
>   pixel #1 along bottom edge.** Error:Failed to run command:
>     /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt
>   s -i
>   /Users/Shravan/Documents/Git/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/password.9.png
>   -o /Users/Shravan/Documents/Git/ics-openvpn/main/build/intermediates/res/normal/debug/drawable-mdpi-v4/password.9.png
>   Error Code:   42 Output: Error:9-patch image
>   /Users/Shravan/Documents/Git/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/password.9.png
>   **malformed.**
>            Ticks in transparent frame must be black or red.
>            Found at pixel #1 along bottom edge. :main:mergeNormalDebugResources FAILED Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':main:mergeNormalDebugResources'.
>
> > Error: Failed to run command:       /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt
> >     s -i
> >     /Users/Shravan/Documents/Git/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/password.9.png
> >     -o /Users/Shravan/Documents/Git/ics-openvpn/main/build/intermediates/res/normal/debug/drawable-mdpi-v4/password.9.png
> >     Error Code:       42   Output:    ERROR: 9-patch image
> >     /Users/Shravan/Documents/Git/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/password.9.png
> >     malformed.
> >                  Ticks in transparent frame must be black or red.
> >                  Found at pixel #1 along bottom edge.

so far I couldn't find anything useful.

Renaming 9.png to .png makes UI problem.

Comment: Make sure that your black is totally black and doesn't have any alpha value at all. Same with the transparent, make sure it is totally transparent

Comment: @MikeWallaceDev - Yes transparent is completely transparent and black is completely black.

Comment: It seems very clear: `Ticks in transparent frame must be black or red. - Found at pixel #1 along bottom edge`